# In WLS regression, what is the appropriate symbol for the common variance of the disturbances?

Tags: regression, weighted-regression

In the context of estimating a regression model by weighted least squares, what is the appropriate or most commonly used symbol for the common homoscedastic variance (assuming the weightings are correct) of the disturbances based on the weighted variables? Is it appropriate to use $\sigma_0^2$?

Comment: $\sigma^2_0$ seems perfectly reasonable.

Comment: I have seen more often the expression $\sigma^2V$ for the covariance matrix of the disturbances.